# Error in smtp mail sending in aspdotnet using csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have shared my code below which throws errors while sending mail.

```js
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com", "Customer");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("reciever@gmail.com", "HR");
        const string fromPassword = "senderpass";
        const string subject = "Subject";
        const string body = "Body";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword);

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

this is the updated code but this also not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: Have you configured Gmail account to Send Emails ? i.e Turning on less secure apps on GMail

Comment: yes less secure apps on gmail is turned on...

Comment: please all friends help me for this problem....?

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your host from the Web-config as below:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="mail####hr@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="mail####hr@gmail.com" password="##########"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

In your class file change the method as follows and let me know:

```
   string strMailBody ="test";
   string strToEmailId ="da###dotnet@gmail.com";
   string strSubject = "Mail Testing";
   SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();
   Client.EnableSsl = true;
   System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    message.To.Add("mail####hr@gmail.com");
            message.Bcc.Add(strToEmailId);// (ToEmailId);
            message.Subject = strSubject;// "Subject";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = strMailBody;//Content;
            try
            {
                Client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: after this code error not resolved......#Server does not support secure connections.# this error comes.

Comment: @danishdotnet try with port `465`

Comment: .Net framework is 4.0 and nothing I have sent only one word as simple text.

Comment: I have try port 465 also

Comment: @danishdotnet dont try to edit my answer , u need to update the Question of what you tried by keep a sub heading as *update*

Comment: dear I have run it on iis. so is that occur problem in that?

Comment: port 25 in my post but I have tried 465 also but that also not worked...